# Building card game need same cards to match in value

Tags: java, arrays

I am building a war card game for an assignment I have the game built and it is working but I am running into the issue such as card 10 jack of spades is less in value as say card 23 the jack of hearts. Looking for advice about the best way to be able to compare the cards to see if they are equal.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WarGame {

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        DeckOfCards d = new DeckOfCards();
        int input = 0; 
        int computer = 0;
        int you = 0;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("\n1.To play\n2.Exit\nEnter the choice:");
        input = sc.nextInt();
        while (input != 2) {
            if (input == 1) {
                System.out.print("\n\nEnter the value of the card:");
                int card = sc.nextInt();
                if (card >= 0 && card <= 51) {
                    int systemCard = d.computerTurn(card);
                    System.out.println("Your card - " + d.inputCard(card));
                    System.out.println("Computer card - " + d.inputCard(systemCard));
                    if(systemCard > card)
                        ++computer;
                    else
                        ++you;
                    System.out.println("The winner is " + (systemCard > card ? "Computer" : "You"));
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid card");
                }
            }
            else {
            System.out.println("That is an invalid selection please choose 1 or 2.");
            }
            System.out.print("\n1.To play\n2.Exit\nEnter the choice:");
            input = sc.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("Total Wins by Computer: "+ computer);
        System.out.println("Total Wins by You: "+ you);
        if (computer > you)
            System.out.println("Computer is the champion");
        else if (computer == you)
            System.out.println("Its a Tie");
        else
            System.out.println("You are the champion");
    }
    }

    class DeckOfCards {
        String suits[] = {"Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs"};
        Random ran = new Random();
        int systemWin = 0;
        int playerWin = 0;
        String inputCard(int card) {
            int suit = card / 13; //assigning suit to your card
            int rank = card % 13; //Assigning rank to your card
            String out = "";
            switch (rank) { //Setting up face cards for the cases
            case 0:
                out = "Ace of " + suits[suit];
                break;
            case 10:
                out = "Jack of " + suits[suit];
                break;
            case 11:
                out = "Queen of " + suits[suit];
                break;
            case 12:
                out = "King of " + suits[suit];
                break;
            default:
                out = rank + 1 + " of " + suits[suit]; //Adding one to remainder so it will go from 2-10 instead of 1-9
                break;
            }
            return out;
        }

        int computerTurn(int playerRank) { //Keeping track of the wins for computer and player
            int systemRank = this.ran.nextInt(51);
            if (systemRank > playerRank)
                systemWin++;
            else
                playerWin++;
            return systemRank;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have code that computes the *rank* of a card (I see it in the `DeckOfCards` class), perhaps you should be comparing those rather than the overall card "number"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're comparing the index to your deck rather than the card values themselves. If I'm understanding, you want to compare d.inputCard(card) with d.inputCard(systemCard) instead of card with systemCard. But of course, that's a String. Having a hard time following the code :-).

Comment: sorry I am new to programming yes I would like to compare the ranks of the cards instead of placement in the array so king of hearts equals king of spades and so on. I tried to edit the code you suggested but it gave me an error for some reason.